# IIS Application pool stop every 15 days without any configuration

Tags: asp.net, iis, model-view-controller, application-pool, windows-server-2019

On a Windows instance a specific application pool stops every 15 days and we have to manually restart that Under the event logs we are getting `dotnet clr.dll` error given below.

> Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 10.0.17763.1, time
> stamp: 0xcfdb13d8 Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.7.3610.0,
> time stamp: 0x5e13fa89 Exception code: 0xc00000fd Fault offset:
> 0x000000000012ebdc Faulting process id: 0x2678 Faulting application
> start time: 0x01d7069cd23d6f15 Faulting application path:
> c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe Faulting module path:
> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll Report Id:
> b44401f0-97b2-4b8c-8fba-703227faec12 Faulting package full name:
> Faulting package-relative application ID:

What should be the process for debugging this issue to get the root cause?

I am new to server management and processes so please bear with me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Typical native crashes. Open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com as it is not trivial to debug such with DebugDiag and WinDbg.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a StackOverflow Exception, which is caused by unbounded recursion (a function repeatedly calling itself, etc). You can track the problem down using DebugDiag and WinDbg.

DebugDiag can be configured to generate a crash dump when the StackOverflowException occurs.

Download at [Debug Diagnostic Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=58210).

About how to use the Debug Diagnostics tool to troubleshoot a process that has stopped responding in IIS you can refer to this link: [How to use the Debug Diagnostics tool](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-use-the-debug-diagnostics-tool-to-troubleshoot-a-process-that-has-stopped-responding-in-iis-995db9a3-a3be-6d20-cf2f-c48101a64444).

Debugging tools for Windows is part of the Windows SDK and can be downloaded at [Download the Windows Driver Kit (WDK)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/hardware/gg463009/.). To use WinDbg, you'll need to get the symbols files. [Download the symbol files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugger-download-symbols) and put them in a local folder. [Getting Started with WinDbg](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/getting-started-with-windbg).

In the results, it should be clear what the problem is.